# in org-mode, how to make RETURN delete highlighted region?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I know this isn't default Emacs behavior, but I'd like to make it so that when text is highlighted and I hit RETURN, the highlighted region gets deleted and the same time that the newline is added. This works when I highlight text and enter an alphanumeric character, but not with RETURN. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
(define-key org-mode-map
    (kbd "RET")
    (lambda()
      (interactive)
      (if (region-active-p)
          (delete-region (region-beginning)
                         (region-end))
        (call-interactively 'org-return))))
```

Comment: It successfully deletes highlighted text. But now when I hit RETURN normally when there's no highlighted text, it enters 2 newlines instead of 1.

Comment: OK, you can remove `(newline)` then.